# Postfix send mail problem "connection timed out"

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtualbox, postfix

I have Windows 7 local machine and virtualbox Ubuntu virtual machine.
i have installed Postfix on it and configured it, but when I try to send test mail I get the following error (in var/log/mail.log file):

> warning: relayhost configuration problem
>
> 6027284D93: to=my@yahoo.com, relay=none, delay=54797,
>   delays=54797/0.22/0.06/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (Host or domain
>   name not found. Name service error for name=testubu.com type=AAAA:
>   Host not found)

my postfix main.cf file:

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.testubu.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydomain=testubu.com
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, testubu.com, smtp-VirtualBox, localhost.localdomain, localhost,
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
#proxy_interfaces =
```

testubu.com is not real domain

> postfix check
>
> postfix status
>   no errors

I have commented relayhost and "warning: relayhost configuration problem" have solved, but I can't send mails. Now in my /var/log/myl.log file:

```
> connect to rilf-cz.mail.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.202]:25:
> Connection timed out
```

When I tried this in terminal:

> traceroute -p 25 rilf-cz.mail.protection.outlook.com

I got the following:

```
traceroute to rilf-cz.mail.protection.outlook.com (213.199.154.202), 64 hops max
  1   10.0.2.2  0,206ms  0,149ms  0,149ms 
  2   10.0.2.2  4,566ms  4,498ms  2,496ms
```

It looks like, nothing happened out of the virtualbox. I disabled all firewalls
I changed the NAT for the bridge. Now the traceroute looks better, but the problem still remains.

```
connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: 716E6882AE: uid=0 from=<root@smtp-VirtualBox>
 716E6882AE: message-id=<20180925094651.716E6882AE@mail.testubu.com>
716E6882AE: from=<root@smtp-VirtualBox>, size=380, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
connect to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[74.6.137.64]:25: Connection timed out
connect to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.137.159.25]:25: Connection timed out
connect to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[66.218.85.52]:25: Connection timed out

Comment: there is no such file. there is cat /var/log/mail.log

Comment: Can you give the output of ```ping -w 3 google.com``` ?

Comment: PING google.com (172.217.169.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sof02s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=28.6 ms
64 bytes from sof02s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=29.4 ms
64 bytes from sof02s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.142): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=28.4 ms

Comment: from windows telnet myubuntuip 25 'code'telnet 192.168.0.15 25
Trying 192.168.0.15...
Connected to 192.168.0.15.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.testubu.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

Comment: perhaps it comes out of the Linux theme

Comment: I guess it's something related to the fact of being a virtualbox server. I will take a closer look as soon as I can. But seems like to be a problem related to this ` relayhost configuration problem`

Comment: it may be necessary to configure **proxy_interfaces** in main.cf file?

Comment: sorry for the delay, could you please comment this line? ```relayhost = testubu.com``` then restart postfix and try again, in case of error please update your mail log please

Comment: it is commented

Comment: and which error message are you getting now? in var/log/mail.log

Comment: `postfix/qmgr[2950]: ED8BE82B11: from=<root@smtp-VirtualBox>, size=356, nrcpt=1 (queue active)`

Comment: `connect to rilf-cz.mail.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.234]:25: Connection timed out`

Comment: `to=, relay=none, delay=60, delays=0.04/0.01/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to rilf-cz.mail.protection.outlook.com[213.199.154.234]:25: Connection timed out)`

Comment: Seems this is a problem regarding the fact of using virtual box. Could you try to send emails internally? for example user1@testubu.com and user2@testubu.com?

Comment: I'm new and I do not know how to do it. it will take time until I figure it out. if you know the guide, please give me the link.